# Why does $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (1/2)^{n-m} = 0$?

Tags: calculus, limits

Given $n > m \in \mathbb{N}$.

Why does $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-m} = 0$$

It's trivial that the terms approach $0$, but why is the limit exactly $0$?

Comment: What is the definition of $\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{2}^{n-m}=0}$ ?

Comment: @Taladris Yeah good point, sometimes I forget that the limit is $\forall \epsilon > 0$.

Comment: "It's trivial that the terms approach $0$": what do you even mean by that if not "the limit is zero"?

Answer (score 8):

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}(\frac{1}{2})^{n-m} =\frac{1}{2^{-m}}\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{2^{n}} = 0$$

Answer (score 5):

If $m \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\varepsilon > 0$ we have
$$
(\frac{1}{2})^{n-m} < \varepsilon
$$
whenever $n \geq \lceil m - \frac{\log \varepsilon}{\log 2} \rceil$,
so by definition the sequence under consideration converges for all $m \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Well, the absolute value is smaller than $\epsilon$.